# Android Dynamic BroadcastReceiver not receiving broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am trying to set an alarm for a 15 minute reminder (Testing with 5 seconds first). When I register the receiver in my Manifest, it works perfect. When I try to set it as a dynamic broadcast receiver, I can't get it to work. The `onReceive()` method doesn't get called at all. I can see this by putting in `Log.d()` entries

The reason I need to convert it to a dynamic broadcast receiver is because I can't figure out how to access my `MainActivity` from inside the `onReceive()` method, as I need to perform some UI tasks like show a notification etc.

I am setting up the AlarmManager like this:

```
        fun snoozeTask(context: Context, taskId: String, snoozeTime: Long) {
            alarmIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java).let { intent ->
                intent.putExtra("taskId", taskId)
                intent.action = AlarmReceiver.SNOOZE_TASK
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, ALARM_REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
            }

            (context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as? AlarmManager)?.let { alarmManager ->
                val hasPermissions = alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()
                AlarmManagerCompat.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(alarmManager, AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, snoozeTime, alarmIntent)
            }
        }
```

and then my `onReceive` method:

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    companion object {
        const val SNOOZE_TASK = "com.my.app.SNOOZE_TASK"
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        when (intent.action) {
            AlarmManager.ACTION_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM_PERMISSION_STATE_CHANGED -> {
                // reschedule all the exact alarms
                //TODO: When the user revokes permission for
                // <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
            }
            SNOOZE_TASK -> {
                val taskId = intent.extras?.getString("taskId")
                val snoozeTime = intent.extras?.getLong("snoozeTime")
            }
            else -> Log.d("TAG", "AlarmReceiver::onReceive::ELSE")
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my MainActivity I have this:

```
private var alarmReceiver: AlarmReceiver = AlarmReceiver()
```

and then in MainActivity `onCreate`:

```
registerReceiver(alarmReceiver, IntentFilter(AlarmReceiver.SNOOZE_TASK))
```

With the same code, this works when I register it in the Manifest. When I try to register in MainActivity, it doesn't work.

Eventually I want to pass some `MutableLiveData` to the constructor of my `AlarmReceiver` class so when I receive the `taskId`, it gets passed back to MainActivity this way.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: are you testing it while the MainActivity is open (and on top)? If not, the receiver is probably getting killed when the activity is killed. If I'm right, then you'll need to register it in your Application() class instead, but even then it'll be killed when the application is killed. If you want it there permanently, it has to be done in Manifest

Comment: is `onReceive()` being called when the alarm goes off?

Comment: The app is open. I'm triggering the broadcast from a button press in the app. No, the `onReceive()` method is not being called at all.